# Windows 10 refresh and effect on the registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, refresh

Windows 10 offers what many seem to call a "Refresh" option, which behaves somewhat like a fresh install except many user files are kept. This can be found in Update & Security, under Recovery and Reset this PC, where you opt to keep your files.

What happens to the registry when this is run? Is the registry completely reset to factory defaults, or is it left intact?

I ask this question because I have remotely been helping a user clean their computer. After refreshing, AVG found many (400+) registry errors. My first guess was that the refresh option kept the registry as-is while removing programs, which would result in these errors. I do not understand why a fresh registry would have so many errors.

Comment: " what happens to the registry when this is run?" - Windows 10 is reinstalled.  This means the Registry is rebuilt.  The registery is meant to have things it.  Why do you want to refresh your system?

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the response. I have edited the question to include my motivation, which should have been in there originally.

Comment: " AVG found many (400+) registry errors." - These are not actual errors.  The Registry is designed to be populated, and despite a huge scam to say otherwise in order to sell software, clearing it does not help with performance.  " I do not understand why a fresh registry would have so many errors." - AVG makes some of the worst software on the planet that is the reason, AVG is finding errors, they are not actual errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refresh your system, the Windows registry goes back to "factory-default" as you might say.

Running a Registry cleaner on your PC is pretty useless and sometimes adversely affects your system. There are numerous websites that emphasize this, for example, [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/171633/why-using-a-registry-cleaner-wont-speed-up-your-pc-or-fix-crashes/) and [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dont-believe-the-hype-registry-cleaners-dont-make-windows-faster/).

When AVG found those errors, it plainly showed that it didn't do any real registry cleaning. As @Ramhound mentioned, the errors that AVG found were not actual errors, but was probably an attempt to impress you on buying some of their paid software.

Comment: It is also quite possible that the 400+ errors that AVG found, were made by AVG itself. ;)

Comment: Many programs flag registry entries as errors,  if they point to a file that no longer exists on the system, say a removed DLL.  The problem with fixing "registry errors" is that unless the entry is starting a program that no longer exists, removing the entry does not improve system performance, the registry is designed to expand and contract.  You should allow allow the program that create the entry, remove the entry, otherwise many times you end up with a system that cannot be booted.